# How to have intellij use gradle build directory instead of out

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle plugin that generates some resources in `build/resources` directory. When I run the program from within IntelliJ it doesn't find the resource on classpath.

Intellij uses `out` directory instead of gradle's `build`. `build` is only used by gradle tasks such as `jar` etc. Both `build` and `out` hold duplicate copies of the compiled Java files.

How do I have Intellij use the same directory as Gradle for compilation output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out after a while.

Under `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner` select `Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle`.

This makes IntelliJ delegate its build operations to gradle instead of using its own compiler. The `out` directory would no longer be generated and `build` would be put on the classpath when you run a class.

I haven't noticed any performance differences. Probably since Gradle too uses incremental compilation and a daemon for faster subsequent builds.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Active Tool(Gradle) in IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Unlink Gradle Project(Delete)

Comment: this solved the problem for me, by recreating the internal model